# How to speed up processing models in R?

Tags: r, performance, iteration, lme4

I am trying to run the maximal `glmer` model below in R using the `lme4` package but it has taken more than 24 hours so far without any luck.

```
library(lme4)
maxwvq <- glmer(match~Listgp+context+length+age+ I(age^2) + gender+ freq.+ 
                      I(freq.^2) + vowel.quality + 
                      Listgp:context+ Listgp:length+ 
                      Listgp:age+Listgp:gender+Listgp:freq.+
                      Listgp:vowel.quality + context:length+context:age+
                      context:gender+context:freq.+
                      context:vowel.quality + length:age+length:gender+
                      length:freq.+length:vowel.quality + 
                      age:gender+age:freq.+age:vowel.quality + 
                      gender:freq.+ gender:vowel.quality + 
                      freq.:vowel.quality+ 
                      (Listgp+age+gender|stimulus) + 
                      (length+context+freq.+vowel.quality|listener), 
                data = SBwritten, family = "binomial", 
                control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)), nAGQ =1)
```

Below is an excerpt of the data.

```
'> tail(SBwritten)
listener Listgp gender age vowel.quality st.vowel stimulus.presentation     match length
```

787     TQ22     TQ Female  26             i       ii               written     mismatch   long
788     TQ22     TQ Female  26             i       ii               written     ?iis    match   long
789     TQ22     TQ Female  26             u       uu               written     mismatch   long
790     TQ22     TQ Female  26             u       uu               written    mismatch   long
791     TQ22     TQ Female  26             u       uu               written     mismatch   long
792     TQ22     TQ Female  26             u       uu               written     mismatch   long
       context nature freq.
787          q   real  6.40
788 pharyngeal   real  0.54
789      plain   real  0.25
790   emphatic   real  0.53
791          q   real  0.13
792 pharyngeal   real  0.32'

Is there a way to speed up processing the model or to simplify it?

Appreciating your help.

Comment: Please provide data (you make want to use a smaller example dataset to produce a reproducible example if your dataset is large). You can use `dput` to share it or call a builtin dataset with `data()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your model is so complex that I would consider trying to fit it nonsensical. This is most likely very much over-fitting.

Comment: Thanks Hack-R. I added some part of the data in my post if that helps.

Comment: Roland. I'm beginning to think you might be right after all but let's see if there is any useful tip out there. Who knows?

Comment: I actually got the model to converge:)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue and was able to get the model to converge. I simplified the random effects structure by including only one slope (only the variables of main experimental interest) for each random effect; that is (Listgp|stimulus)+ (vowel.quality|listener) for the model above.